# Asymptotic of $a_n$ as thresholds of inverse power sums

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics, recurrence-relations, recursion

## Problem

Let $a_{n> 0}$ be a monotonically increasing integer sequence. $a_1 = 1$, and the rest of $a_n$ is defined through the recursion relation 
\begin{equation}
a_{n+1} = \text{argmax}_{A\in \mathbb{Z}^+}  \left\{ S_n(A) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{(A - a_i)^{\mu}}> \frac{1}{2}  \right\} 
\end{equation}
(i.e. $a_n$ is equal to the maximal integer $A$ that satisfies the inequality $S_n(A) > \frac{1}{2} $). Here $0 < \mu < \infty$.

**Q: What is the asymptotic behavior of $a_n$ in terms of $n$?**

*Note*: Note $S_n(A)$ is monotonically decreasing for $A \ge a_n + 1$. Since we have $S_n(a_n+1) > 1$ and $S_n( \infty) = 0 $, the maximal integer always exists to define the sequence.

The asymptotic behaivor should be (I think) identical for the **real** sequence. Let $a_1 = 1$ , and $a_{n+1}$ can be recursively solved from
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{(a_{n+1}  - a_i)^{\mu}} =  \frac{1}{2} 
\end{equation}

### Partial solution:

I managed to obtain the following leading order behaviors
\begin{equation}
a_n \sim 
\left\lbrace
\begin{aligned}
  & n  & \quad   \mu > 1 \\
  & n^{\frac{1}{\mu}} & \quad  0 < \mu <   1 \\
\end{aligned} \right. 
\end{equation}

Let us start with the ansatz $a_n \sim k n $, where $k$ is a constant. Plugging into the recursion relation
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{( a_{N+1} - a_n )^\mu   }  \sim  \frac{1}{k^{\mu} } \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{(N + 1  - n)^\mu} 
\end{equation}
The sum is convergent when $\mu > 1$, so that the LHS can be set to $\frac{1}{2}$ if we adjust $k$. The linear solution works for $\mu > 1$

When $ 0 < \mu < 1$, we try a power function ansatz $a_n \sim n^{\alpha}$. Again we use the recursive relation
\begin{equation}
  \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{( a_{N+1} - a_n )^\mu   } \sim  \frac{1}{N^{\alpha \mu}} \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{( ( 1 + \frac{1}{N})^\alpha  - (\frac{n}{N} )^{\alpha}  )^\mu   }
\sim \frac{N}{N^{\alpha \mu}} \int_0^1 \frac{1}{( ( 1 + \frac{1}{N})^\alpha  - x^{\alpha}  )^\mu } dx 
\end{equation}
Since $0 < \mu < 1$, the integral is convergent even at $x \rightarrow $1. For the whole expression to be $\frac{1}{2}$, we must have $\alpha \mu = 1$, thus $\alpha = \frac{1}{\mu}$.

**Update v3**:

When $\mu  = 1$, one guess that $a_n \sim n \ln n$ based on the numerical data and check 
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n= 1}^{N} \frac{1}{( N + 1) \ln ( N + 1 ) - n \ln n}
\end{equation}
converges in $N\rightarrow \infty$. Following the same trick for $\mu < 1$, one can convert this to an integral
\begin{equation}
\int_0^1 \frac{1}{( 1 + \frac{1}{N} ) \ln ( N + 1 ) - x \ln (xN)  } dx 
\end{equation}We need to make sure the integral converges at $x = 1$, so we take expand the denominator around $x = 1$
\begin{equation}
\frac{\ln N}{ N}  + (1 - x) (\ln N + 1 )  + \mathcal{O}(\frac{1}{N} )
\end{equation}
If we integrate around $x = 1$, we will get 
\begin{equation}
\frac{- \ln (\ln N / N )}{\ln N +1}  \sim 1 
\end{equation}
when $N \rightarrow \infty$. So the integral is finite, and we have $a_n \sim n \ln n $ when $\mu \rightarrow 1$.

**Numerical Test**:

The numerical test confirmed the scaling.

(In v1, I stated that the numerical test suggested a logarithmic correction. Not there is not. It was due to an incorrect implementation to numerically search $a_n$. )

### Question:

At this stage (v3), the problem has been solved to my satisfaction. 
But you are welcome to post your solutions.

In the numerical data, I also observed that when $\mu \rightarrow 1$, $a_n$ first behaves as $n \ln n$, and then transits to $n^{1/\mu}$ or $kn$ for larger $n$. I wonder if there is any quantitative way to describe this cross over behavior.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the meaning of $\text{argmax}$？

Comment: @RocHang, it means the argument at which a function takes maximal value. In the present context, it means the maximal integer $A$ to satisfy $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{(A- a_i)^{\mu}} > 1/2$.